# produce standalone html for chunks of an Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am searching for a way to produce a standalone HTML document from a chunk in Rmarkdown.

My example is this:
I have an Rmarkdown document for my analysis.
In one chunk of code, I produce interactive plotly plots that are quit long to load when I open the HTML.
I am looking for an option that would create another HTML document for this particular chunk and put a link to it in its place in the master HTML document.

I am sure I could manage to do something like that with a bit of tweaking with another script, but I would like to know if there is not a simpler option first.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just take the chunk and have it be it's own RMD file and just call the RMD file inside the master Rmarkdown file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can nest documents using [knitr child documents](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/). Put the chunk you want to isolate in its own Rmd (say, `child.Rmd`), then use this syntax to insert it in the master document:

````
```{r child='child.Rmd'}
```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jonathan, however what I want to do would be the opposite.

Comment: That is to have the code in the master doc, and to produce a child HTML document. I don't know if what I am saying is clear. But the section on the standalone in your link could be a lead I could use. (sorry for the 2 part comment, I am new on stack)